# How to inject template code in Plone?

Tags: python, html, templates, plone, zope

My goal is to inject some HTML-Code in front of *every* Plone article (between the page's header and the first paragraph)? I'm running Plone 4. Does anyone have a hint on how to realize that?

The other question is: is it possible to place some HTML code randomly in every Plone article?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [viewlets](https://plone.org/documentation/kb/customization-for-developers/viewlets) for both usecases. A viewlet can be inserted in different parts of the rendered page, depending on both the viewlet manager you register it to and and what interfaces the viewlet applies to.

The viewlet manager determines the location the viewlet is inserted at, and the interface you register the viewlet for determines on what kind of URL the viewlet will be visible at. Registering for `"*"` means show everywhere, and registering it for `"Products.ATContentTypes.interfaces.IATDocument"` means it'll only be visible when viewing a Page.

To see what viewlet managers are available and what viewlets are registered there, for any given URL, just add "/@@manage-viewlets" to the URL. There you can see that there is a `plone.abovecontent` and a `plone.abovecontenttitle` viewlet manager that would enable you to insert HTML there. Most of these are defined in the `plone.app.layout` package, and you'll need to find the interface that is registered with that name there (find it in your eggs directory of the buildout).

You register a viewlet using ZCML, so you need to already have a python package that is loaded for your site. To insert an arbitrary template, simply register it with the `browser:viewlet` directive:

```xml
<browser:viewlet
    name="your.html.snippet"
    for="Products.ATContentTypes.interfaces.IATDocument"
    manager="plone.app.layout.viewlet.interfaces.IAboveContent"
    template="htmlsnippet.pt"
    permission="zope.Public"
    />
```

Now, a viewlet based on the `htmlsnippet.pt` template is registered for the `plone.abovecontent` viewlet manager. That template is a full zope page template, so you can use things like internationalisation in there:

```
<div i18n:domain="your">
    <h3 i18:translate="html_snippet_header">This is a snippet of HTML that'll be injected into all Pages!</h3>
</div>
```

You can also add a full browser view class to back up the viewlet, and the template can access that class via the "view/" namespace, so you could add a method there to return random text to be inserted.

You can either manually enable the viewlet via the aforementioned '/@@manage-viewlets' URL or you can use a GenericSetup profile, where viewlets.xml let's you manage the registrations and ordering of viewlets:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object>
  <order manager="plone.abovecontent" skinname="My Theme"
         based-on="Plone Default">
    <viewlet name="your.html.snippet" insert-before="*"/>
  </order>
</object>
```

For more information, I refer you to the [viewlets tutorial](https://plone.org/documentation/kb/customizing-main-template-viewlets) on Plone.org.

Comment: Hi Martijn, I was away for a while and returned to this thread. What a fantastic description of injecting HTML into Plone sites! Many, many thanks for your help and such a detailed description. I'll try your way the next days. Cheerio, Chris.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could approach this from a Javascript way? A lot of applications have like a global js file, that's included in all pages. Starting from that you could modify the DOM easily.

Comment: The JS approach should only be needed when manipulating the content of a the content type itself (so the title, description or body text), and then only if you cannot do it with a registered transformation in the portal_transforms tool. Still, I've done that before, but used a viewlet to render the JavaScript. For most use-cases a viewlet is perfect (see my answer).