# Customize a document_view and add a div?

Tags: view, plone, customization

This feels like a newbie question but:

I am trying to create a new page from the drop-down display menu so that I can supply a background color to the page (so end user doesn't have to go into the html and add a div). I tried adding a new (empty) div to the template but it's not working. Is this even possible?

Here is my code (my div is called "s_holder"):

```
 <metal:field use-macro="python:here.widget('text', mode='view')">
Body text
        </metal:field>

        <div metal:use-macro="here/document_relateditems/macros/relatedItems">
            show related items if they exist
        </div>

        <div tal:replace="structure provider:plone.belowcontentbody" />

    </tal:main-macro>
</metal:main>
 <div id="s_holder"></div><!--end s holder-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503861/how-to-inject-template-code-in-plone/6504716#6504716

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do it.  I'm not convinced it's a good idea :-), but you need the <div> to be *inside* the main_macro (your example HTML is invalid - you have a </tal:main-macro> and no start tag, but I'm assuming you just cut and pasted the last part of the template here, because that template would never display, if it was written that way.

That said, how exactly are you adding it to "the drop-down display menu"?

Comment: I was following these instructions: [link](http://www.uwosh.edu/ploneprojects/documentation/how-tos/how-to-hide-selectively-a-pages-description)

Comment: Ah, I see.  I thought you were talking about creating new _Documents_. Note, that document says "you could resort to CSS".  That's not what I'd call a "resort" - it's the logical way to do what you want.

Comment: I do want to use CSS but I need a div in the html (s_holder) first before I can apply css to it. Anwyway, this approach did not work for while I got the new page to show in my drop-down display it was putting the div on all my plone pages (including the home page) but was not putting it in the end user new page where I wanted it.

Comment: Getting the div on all your pages was exactly why it didn't seem like the right solution to me.  There are dozens of DIVs on every page, most of them with class & ID attributes, so it's hard to imagine that you can't find exactly the right one to style.  You can also add stylesheets with conditions that will be loaded only for specific portal types.

Answer (score 0):

For the part of creating the new display view: as @Auspex said, you should put the div inside the macro.

To add your display view to the drop down menu you need to edit every content type. There are two ways of doing this:

1- manually add a "types" folder in the genericsetup profile of your product and put inside one xml file per content type. Ex:

*File.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="File"
    meta_type="Factory-based Type Information with dynamic views"
    i18n:domain="plone" xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n">
    <property name="view_methods">
        <element value="file_view"/>
        <element value="myniewfantastic_view"/>
    </property>
</object>
```

2- in the ZMI -> portal_types edit every content type to add your display view and then in the portal_setup tool export the step for types. Extract the xml definitions from the downloaded archive to your genericsetup profile (in the "types" folder) and then edit them to remove unuseful parts as above.